# My right click options in ubuntu different after xkill?

Tags: icons, trash

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04LTS. I have used the `xkill` and deleted the trash icon. 
After that when I clicked the right mouse button options seems to be reduced.

[image: screenshot of my right click]

Actually, I'm new to Ubuntu. So please help.

Comment: Whoever told you that [xkill](https://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xkill.1.xhtml) is an appropriate tool to remove the trash icon from your desktop obviously doesn't know what `xkill` does. Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: I restarted the system and it looks fine. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By killing trash you've killed Nautilus which killed Desktop folder(in some way). Try restarting nautilus.

Comment: It's correct, OP seems to have killed `nautilus-desktop` process by applying `xkill` on desktop. Restarting Nautilus should start the process again.